# Как лучше всего различать автоматический запуск и ручной запуск приложения C#, инициированный пользователем?

Tags: c#, winforms, автозапуск

Я разрабатываю приложение, которое должно запускаться самостоятельно, например через планировщик задач или автозагрузку в свернутом режиме, с отображением значка в трее. Но при этом при запуске по ярлыку и должен отображаться интерфейс приложения. Каким образом лучше различать вариант запуска?

Я предполагаю, что можно использовать аргументы. Но не представляю как. Сделал запуск автозапуск через планировщик задач - там можно прописать аргументы. в форме прописал: ShowlnTaskbar - False WindowState - Minimized заускается в трее ()

Считаю, что можено сделать так: В планировщике прописать аргументы, при наличии аргументов - запускать в трее. затем при первом запуске приложения добавить автоматическое создание задания в планировщике (автозапуск приложения с аргументами).

Или это плохая идея?

Comment: Да, такое решается через аргументы запуска.